# Azure AD Authentication on React Frontend with Node.js Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure

I would like to add an Azure AD configuration to my React&Node.js project. What I want is to log in  on Frontend using Azure AD and then send a request with f.e `axios` to my backend written in Node.js, so that Node.js knows that the user is logged in and can perform the request. I was reading tutorials/documentation on Microsoft site for all day, but I still don't know how and where to start. Basically, almost every Microsoft Tutorial is either to call a Microsoft Graph API from Node.js or from React.js. I completely do not want to use Microsoft Graph. I just want to have simple login on frontend and protected endpoints from un-logged user on backend. The other tutorials that I find are too complicated f.e  `https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api` . I understand the concept of App registration, client id, tenant id and etc. but I simply don't know how to write a code that: login, send the request with token - then is accepted/declined by Node.js .

If by any chance, somehow did an application like that, or can provide me a link to a well written tutorial, so I would understand and recreate it in my scenario, I would be grateful.

Comment: have any luck? I am trying to do something similar and like you I am not enjoying the documentation.